# Basic to Dynamic Disk

Tags: windows-server-2008

I'm trying to setup a software RAID on windows 2008 and I've found a number of guides on how to do it.  Whenever I try to convert from Basic to Dynamic Disk the option isn't even available let alone grayed out.  What would cause this?  I'm looking for it by right clicking on the volume.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should right-click on the ***disk***, not the volume.

Comment: Awesome.  The "Add Mirror" is still grayed out though.

Comment: You need to have another dynamic disk in the system, with enough empty (unpartitioned) space to hold the mirror.

Comment: I was trying to add a mirror to the other drive.  I was reading it thinking they meant as "Add as Mirror"...